# Using onClick to router.push, fetch data and update page in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I am newcomer to react and trying to execute a GraphQL query, to update `data` on a page depending on which link a user clicks (check the two `onClick`s in code below).

When the user has clicked a link `handleSubmit` should also update the URL via `router.push` (updated URL should look like: `http://localhost:3000/bonustype?=value`), without any page refresh. However when I try to use `router.push` I get the following error:

> Server Error
> Error: No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.

After the link has been clicked and URL updated the GraphQL query should "execute" again using the updated slug (with value from link).

Been stuck with this for a few hours, appreciate any help or input. The code is from my main index page and the current url when it runs is `localhost:3000/`.

**How would you solve this?**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Head from "next/head";
import Featured from "../components/index/Featured";
import { API_URL } from "@/config/index";

import {
  ApolloClient,
  inMemoryCache,
  gql,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";

export default function HomePage({ casinos }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    router.push(`/bonustype?term=${value}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <div>
          <div className={featured.featuredMenu}>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#" value="Swish" onClick={handleSubmit()} className={featured.active}>
                  <Star className={featured.menuIcon} />

                  <div>Highest User Rating</div>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#" value="Swish" onClick={handleSubmit()}>
                  <TabletAndroid className={featured.menuIcon} />
                  <div>Casinos with Swish</div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          {casinos.map((casino) => (
            <Featured key={casino.id} casino={casino} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const slug = "Visa";
  console.log(slug);

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:1337/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query Casinos($slug: String) {
        casinos(where: { deposit_methods: { name: $slug } }) {
          slug
          name
          logo {
            url
          }
          rating
          owner
          founded
          bonuses {
            name
            slug
            title
            cashable
            bonus_type {
              name
            }
          }
          deposit_methods {
            name
            logo {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      slug,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      casinos: data.casinos,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to update the URL to `/bonustype?term=some_value` but still stay on the homepage?

Comment: correct.  And then "value" should be used to update data on the current page via the graphql query, as you can see the query has a $slug.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong

```
onClick={handleSubmit()}
```

This is correct

```
onClick={() => handleSubmit(`Swiss`)} 
// you need to supply the parameter to handleSubmit for each different call made
```

THEN CHANGE handleSubmit to below

```
const handleSubmit = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    router.push(`/bonustype?term=${value}`);
  };
```

Comment: I tried both but value unfortunately  becomes "undefined" in the console.log ... The push seems to work redirecting to: http://localhost:3000/bonustype?term=undefined  but I also want to prevent the redirect. Value should be used to update data on the current page via the graphql query, as you can see the query has a $slug.

Comment: I have edited my answer to demonstrate an alternative

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `next/router` (current implementation)

You'll first need update the `onClick` callbacks, as they're not being set correctly.

```js
onClick={() => handleSubmit('Swish')}
```

In your `handleSubmit`, you can use the `as` parameter of `router.push` to change the visible URL on the browser while still staying on the same page.

```js
const handleSubmit = (value) => {
    router.push(`/?term=${value}`, `/bonustype?term=${value}`);
};
```

#### Using `next/link` (alternative)

Alternatively, you don't need to use `onClick` and `next/router` for the routing - using `next/link` would probably be a better option in this case. You can replace the `<a>` elements with the following, and still have the same behaviour.

```js
<Link href="/?term=Swish" as="/bonustype?term=Swish">
    <a className={featured.active}>
        <Star className={featured.menuIcon} />
        <div>Highest User Rating</div>
    </a>
</Link>
```

---

No matter which of the above approaches you use, you can then retrieve the query parameter passed in the URL inside `getServerSideProps`.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    const slug = query.term ?? "Visa"; // Defaults to `Visa` if no param is passed

    // Remaining logic...
}
```